# no option to defined SSL handshake timeout in spring integration

Tags: spring, timeout, spring-integration, handshaking

I am using spring integration in one of my application to communicate with bank. On heavy load we are getting error "org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: SSL Handshaking taking too long". Bank ask us to set timeout as 90 sec.
While look into the code of TcpNioSSLConnection class, I found that 30 second is hardcoded.

```
private HandshakeStatus waitForHandshakeData(SSLEngineResult result,
            HandshakeStatus status) thr`enter code here`ows IOException {
            try {
                if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                    logger.trace("Writer waiting for handshake");
                }
            if (!TcpNioSSLConnection.this.semaphore.tryAcquire(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                throw new MessagingException("SSL Handshaking taking too long");
            }
            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                logger.trace("Writer resuming handshake");
            }
            status = runTasksIfNeeded(result);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new MessagingException("Interrupted during SSL Handshaking");
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Please suggest me if there any way to increase ssl handshake timeout

below is my spring integration connection factory configuration

```
 <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
            type="client" port="${cbs.third.party.port}"  host="${cbs.third.party.host}"
            single-use="true" using-nio="true" deserializer="javaDeserializer"
            serializer="javaSerializer" ssl-context-support="sslContextSupport" task-executor="myTaskExecutor"/>
```

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to configure that timeout; I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4183).

You could try setting `use-nio` to `false`; unless you are opening a lot of sockets for long durations, it's not generally required.

Comment: Thank you Gary for your reply. I will check the same